# SQL / DB2 Array in Where declared in with

Tags: sql, arrays, db2

anyone does know a workaround for querying with parameters/variables for usage in where [...] in functions on db2 v11?

what i tried:

```
DECLARE @list varchar(23) = '1,2,3,4'
SELECT ...FROM tbl WHERE col IN (@list)
```

```
WITH test(val) AS (VALUES(ARRAY['5','9']))
SELECT ... FROM table, test WHERE col ANY(val)
```

both do not work, first one isn't db2 compatible, the second ones does not work cause he cant split the values.

any ideas or examples?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tbl t
WHERE EXISTS
(
  select 1
  from xmltable
  (
  'for $id in tokenize($s, ",") return <i>{string($id)}</i>' 
  passing '1,2,3,4' as "s"
  columns 
    tok int path '.'
  ) v
  where v.tok = t.col
);
```

You may use a parameter marker instead of the string constant `1,2,3,4` as for usual string paramter, if you want to provide such a list of integers as a comma separated string at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Declare local temporary table and insert your value list in that ?