# How can i add a simple quote(') to a string separated by comma (,) and use it in IN clause in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I have this db called problem:

```
NAME   | CONTENT
------------
Hello | value1,value2,value3
```

How can convert content in a values for using it with another query IN clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE VALUES IN ( SELECT CONTENT FROM PROBLEM WHERE NAME = 'HELLO');
```

I don't know what the problem is with the subquery but I think it returns a string and it doesn't work.

```
SELECT '''' || REPLACE(CONTENT, ',', ''',''') || '''' AS CONTENT_WITH_QUOTES
FROM PROBLEM
WHERE NAME = 'HELLO';
```

This gives me this **'value1','value2','value3'**
That is exactly with i need but in the subselect doesnt like it!

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE VALUES IN
    (SELECT '''' || REPLACE(CONTENT, ',', ''',''') || '''' AS CONTENT_WITH_QUOTES
     FROM PROBLEM WHERE NAME = 'HELLO')
```

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items, it will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Sometimes its just the card you are dealt, but If you can change your design such that you don't have to do this that'd be better. Can you provide some sample data for TABLE.values? Is that also a comma separated string of multiple values? If it's absolutely unavoidable you could consider the dynamic answer here to separate the values https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961996/how-to-split-a-string-value-based-on-a-delimiter-in-db2. Then pivot so you get 1 record per value item and do your WHERE IN.

Comment: I don't know how temporary table work in db2, but it could be a possibility to create one based on the select that makes the quoted list, and then use the temporary table in the sub-query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL / DB2 Array in Where declared in with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69706526/sql-db2-array-in-where-declared-in-with)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE t
    INNER JOIN PROBLEM p ON LOCATE(','||t.values||',', ','||content||',') > 0
  WHERE p.name='Hello'
```

Basically You are trying to find "**,value,**" in "**,value1,value2,value3,**".

I append commas to start and end to guarantee You won't find e. g. "cat" within value "tomcat".